# Using Testflight, trying to generate Archive but error on chown for Entitlement.plist

Tags: ios, testflight, code-signing-entitlements

I've done the requisite search on Google for the error but haven't found anything useful so I'm posting it here to hopefully get some leads.

I'm using Testflight. Have followed [the directions here](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) for XCode 4.

When I do a Product -> Build for -> Archiving...it compiles and signs using an key
When I do a Product -> Archive...it fails with the message

```
{some stuff before...but I think this is the culprit } /usr/sbin/chown -RH "Entitlements.plist:staff"
"/Users/jtu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-agrwkgvjqjnrrvglrgpdcmvlquzy/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectLite/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Playing Cards Lite.app"
chown: Entitlements.plist: Invalid argument
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

I even tried to change the permissions for the Entitlements.plist file to 777...no luck.

I'm not essentially stuck and can't create an IPA archive for TestFlight.

Any ideas on what I should try?

Comment: You Entitlements file seems to have a strange name, "Entitlements.plist:staff", are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Are you trying to upload a .ipa file to testflight?

Comment: That is part of the syntax for chown (I think). It wants to change the owner of the file to staff.

Comment: @denil I'm trying to generate the IPA file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit. I'm not sure how this came to be but "Entitlements.plist" was entered in as the INSTALL OWNER and ALTERNATE INSTALL OWNER.  So when chown was trying to chown to an owner:group it was using Entitlements.plist:staff!

After I changed it to my user name. All was good. I was able to do Product -> Archive.

[image]